# how to use Tuple in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use tuples so I can use 2 models in the same View and I did this in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index( int id = 0 )
{
    int lastVoyageID = entities.log_voyage.Max(item => item.Num_Voy);

    var first = entities.log_voyage.Where(v => v.Num_Voy == lastVoyageID);
    log_voyage voyage1 = entities.log_voyage.Find(lastVoyageID);
    var second = entities.log_ligne_voyage.Where(x => x.NUM_Voy == lastVoyageID).ToList();
    var t = new Tuple<log_voyage, log_ligne_voyage>(first, second);
    return View(t);
}
```

but I got this:

I don't know what to do? How do I use tuples?

this is the error :

> Can not convert system.Linq.IQueryable  into WebApplication.Models.log_voyage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var first = entities.log_voyage.Where(v => v.Num_Voy == lastVoyageID)` returns collection but Tuple  expects for a single object so it should be;

`var first = entities.log_voyage.Where(v => v.Num_Voy == lastVoyageID).FirstOrDefault()`

And this expression returns collection and Tuple seeks for just one object again

`var second = entities.log_ligne_voyage.Where(x => x.NUM_Voy == lastVoyageID).ToList()`

You might want to change the Tuple signature as `Tuple<log_voyage, List<log_ligne_voyage>>`

Finally,

```
public ActionResult Index( int id = 0 )
{

    int lastVoyageID = entities.log_voyage.Max(item => item.Num_Voy);

    var first = entities.log_voyage.Where(v => v.Num_Voy == lastVoyageID).FirstOrDefault();
    log_voyage voyage1 = entities.log_voyage.Find(lastVoyageID);
    var second = entities.log_ligne_voyage.Where(x => x.NUM_Voy == lastVoyageID).ToList();
    var t = new Tuple<log_voyage, List<log_ligne_voyage>>(first, second);
    return View(t);

}
```